# lossless Video Codec with RGB48 support

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, libavcodec, libav

I am looking for a video codec with the following specs:

- (mathematically) **lossless**
- takes frames with **RGB48** pixel format (16 bit bpc)
- possibility to use via **libav**

I cannot use something like VP9 because it supports only YUV color space and the RGB - YUV conversion is connected with a loss of information.

Anyone any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ffv1 will work but it does not compress much.  I get 100%  recovery with RGB48 tiffs as input to ffv1 and then using `-vcodec tiff` to recreate the tiffs.  Some tiff properties are altered (mainly the orientation).  The ffv1 mkv would not play back well with anything.

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` supports some 10-bit raw RGB codecs like [Blackmagic's r210](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=R210) and [AJA Kona r10K](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=R10k), but not 16 bpc.

There's a full list of `ffmpeg` [lossless codecs](https://antumdeluge.wordpress.com/lossless-ffmpeg-video-encoders/), but some are not for video and the majority don't accept RGB:

```
Lossless:

ffv1 – (FFmpeg Video Codec 1)
flashsv – (Flash Screen Video 1)
gif – (Graphics Interchange Format)
png – (Portable Network Graphics)
qtrle – (Apple Quicktime Animation (RLE))
zmbv – (Zip Motion Block / DosBox Capture Codec)

Lossless Intra Frames Only:

bmp – (Bitmap Image)
dpx – (Digital Picture Exchange)
ffvhuff – (Huffyuv FFmpeg variant)
huffyuv – (HuffYUV)
ljpeg – (Lossless JPEG)
pam – (Portable AnyMap / Netpbm)
pbm – (Portable BitMap / Netpbm)
pcx – (PC Paintbrush / Personal Computer Exchange Image)
pgm – (Portable GrayMap / Netpbm)
pgmyuv – (Portable GrayMap YUV / Netpbm)
ppm – (Portable PixMap / Netpbm)
r10k – (AJA Kona 10-bit RGB Codec)
r210 – (Uncompressed RGB 10-bit)
rawvideo – (Raw Video)
sgi – (Silicon Graphics Image)
sunrast – (Sun Raster Image)
targa – (Truevision TGA Image)
tiff – (Tagged Image File Format)
utvideo – (Ut Video)
v210 – (Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit)
v410 – (Uncompressed 4:4:4 10-bit / SheerVideo?)
xbm – (X BitMap)
xwd – (X Window Dump)
zlib – (Lossless Codec Library ZLIB)

Optionally Lossless:

dirac / libschroedinger – (Dirac Compression Format)
h264 / libx264 / libx264rgb – (H.264 / MPEG-4 AVC)
snow – (Snow)
Optionally Lossless Intra Frames Only:

jpeg2000 / libopenjpeg – (JPEG 2000)
jpegls – (JPEG-LS / Lossless JPEG)
```

Comment: - Options for [h264 / h264rgb lossless](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264), set QP (or CRF) to 0 :

`ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mkv`

 - Options for setting [lossless mode](http://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/lossless.html) on [h265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) (you need to pass it as a codec private option): 

`ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -x265-params lossless=1 output.mkv`

 - For the YUV-based h264 / h265 consider using YUV:4:4:4 input (no color subsampling):

`-pix_fmt yuv444p`